# Any similar thing of quick fixing in intellij like in eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea

eclipse's quick fixing is very useful, is there any similar function in intellij ? I didn't find it, could you help on this ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You refer to the fixes suggested by [Intention Actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intention-actions.html).
The shortcut is <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> in Windows.

See some of the other important shortcuts [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html).